# PyCharm not recognizing my python interpreter and PIP packages. Maybe PATH issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, pycharm

So I have been having issues with getting PyCharm to find my python3 interpreter on my Mac. I have downloaded a few packages with pip from the terminal and when I use the python shell from the terminal and import them, I get no errors.

When I check where these packages are downloaded, I get this path:

> > /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.>7/lib/python3.7/site-packages

So the issue is when I try to use the PyCharm IDE I don't have access to these packages. I have gone into the settings to change the interpreter and I have tried all these options, none of which show my installed packages.

![1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnjKc.png

I have also tried navigating to that path where it shows my packages are downloaded and selecting the python.exe (the highlighted file) I find, but get this error with PyCharm ->

![2]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0RTk.png
![3]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJqCe.png

I have a feeling I am selecting the wrong python.exe but I don't know where to look. I also think the problem could stem from me installing iTerm and the zshrc bash program and it changed my paths, but I don't know why python would be working from my terminal then. Just in case, this is what my Path is in my zshrc file:

- export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
- export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
- export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"

Sorry for the long post and no inline images, this is my first post. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Just trying to get this to work so I can work on a project.

**Update**
just thought it would be useful to know that when i type "which python3" in the terminal it returns -> /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: what happens when you type `which pip`

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is

1. Open the pycharm
2. Go to top left most side on IDE and open FILE dropdown.
3. Open the project which contains PIP files.

By this procedure pycharm automatic detect the virtual environment.